# XML Parsing in Blue Prism

Tags: xml-parsing, blueprism

I'm new to Blue Prism and exploring things on my own.

I'd like to parse the data from XML to Tags in one column and Data available in the tags in another column of an Excel sheet. I've imported the BPA-XML Utility. How to proceed further. Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks much in advance.

Comment: Hi there  can you please add more info she  you say parse xml to tags and also data available to tags in another column. This bit is not clear and sounds like it involves many steps, clarify and maybe I can submit something

Answer (score 1):

To get your XML node:

1. Utility - XML::Read File
2. Then on this text you can use Utility - XML::Get Elements whit the name of your tag.

Example:
[image]

Comment: You can download the Utility - XML file from the Blue Prism homepage via menu Products / Developer Jumpstart. (Login first to see the menu.)

Answer (score -1):

Using MS Excel VBO is pretty easy, there are many helpfull options in this object.

If you work with xml file, in Blue Prism in Object Studio you mainly use Action in you diagram. First use Open Workbook, then if you want to see it on the screen use Show...etc

Its rly self explanatory.